# same thread id when using openmp in android

Tags: android, openmp

I try to use OpenMP in an android application.
While in a test programme, something strange occured:

here is my code to test:

```
    int num_thread = omp_get_num_procs();
    LOGI("openmp available : %d thread(s)." , num_thread);
    omp_set_num_threads(8);
    omp_set_nested(0);

#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        LOGI("Hello world (%d) / (%d)", id,omp_get_num_threads() );
    }
```

While the output from logcat in android studio shows:

```
2020-01-17 14:15:33.425 6961-7005/? I/MarkerTracker-dev: openmp available : 8 thread(s).
2020-01-17 14:15:33.426 6961-7005/? I/MarkerTracker-dev: Hello world (0) / (1)
2020-01-17 14:15:33.426 6961-7196/? I/MarkerTracker-dev: Hello world (0) / (1)
2020-01-17 14:15:33.426 6961-7194/? I/MarkerTracker-dev: Hello world (0) / (1)
2020-01-17 14:15:33.426 6961-7195/? I/MarkerTracker-dev: Hello world (0) / (1)
```

I have some questions:

1. it says there are 8 cores available to use, so I set to use all the 8, while it has started four.
2. the id of all the threads are the same? or did it run four times?
3. why "omp_get_num_threads" always return 1?

Comment: I've never developed on Android so I can only make assumptions here: maybe you linked with a stub OpenMP library that always returns 0 for tid and 1 for size? Apparently, you did launch 4 threads as the logs show, since I suspect the 7194 to 7196 values in prefix might be the threads id in the OS...

Comment: you are making sense ! so I assume openmp is working, but error happened with the library. I will check the library setting.

Answer (score 1):

After several tests I finally make it work.
So the problem should be with the library settings.

In the beginning of this project, I search a lot about the setting of openmp library in a Android Project. And I found many different versions of the settings. (e.g. set "cppFlags", change in the cmakelist, etc). I add them all together. **This may lead to some conflicts**

So I delete all the settings, and only use arguments in cmakelist:

```
find_package(OpenMP QUIET)
if(OpenMP_FOUND)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fopenmp")
else()
    message(WARNING "OpenMP not found.")
endif()
```

And finally, I get the correct output:

```
    int num_thread = omp_get_num_procs();
    LOGI("openmp available : %d thread(s)." , num_thread);
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    omp_set_nested(0);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        LOGI("1. Hello world (%d) / (%d)", omp_get_thread_num(),omp_get_num_threads() );
    }
```

```
2020-01-17 16:18:20.694 21594-21624/? I/MarkerTracker-dev: openmp available : 4 thread(s).
2020-01-17 16:18:20.694 21594-21624/? I/MarkerTracker-dev: 1. Hello world (0) / (4)
2020-01-17 16:18:20.694 21594-21736/? I/MarkerTracker-dev: 1. Hello world (3) / (4)
2020-01-17 16:18:20.694 21594-21734/? I/MarkerTracker-dev: 1. Hello world (1) / (4)
2020-01-17 16:18:20.695 21594-21735/? I/MarkerTracker-dev: 1. Hello world (2) / (4)
```

Comment: Well done solving your issue yourself. That's the best way to learn anyway